# Check user in every controller in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have a user object that has a property 'enabled'. I want every action to first check if the user is enabled before continuing.

Right now I have solved it with a Controller that every other controller extends, but using the `setContainer` function to catch every Controller action feels really hacky.

```php
class BaseController extends Controller{

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
         $this->container = $container;

         $user = $this->getUser();

         // Redirect disabled users to a info page
         if (!$user->isEnabled() && !$this instanceof InfoController) {
             return $this->redirectToRoute('path_to_info');
         }
}
```

I have tried building this using a before filter (http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html), but could not get the User object..any tips?

EDIT:

This is my solution:

```
namespace AppBundle\Security;

use AppBundle\Controller\AccessDeniedController;
use AppBundle\Controller\ConfirmController;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;

class UserEnabledListener
{
    private $tokenStorage;
    private $router;

    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage, Router $router)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();

        /*
         * $controller passed can be either a class or a Closure.
         * This is not usual in Symfony but it may happen.
         * If it is a class, it comes in array format
         */
        if (!is_array($controller)) {
            return;
        }

        $controller = $controller[0];

        // Skip enabled check when:
        // - we are already are the AccessDenied controller, or
        // - user confirms e-mail and becomes enabled again, or
        // - Twig throws error in template
        if ($controller instanceof AccessDeniedController ||
            $controller instanceof ConfirmController ||
            $controller instanceof ExceptionController) {
            return;
        }

        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

        // Show info page when user is disabled
        if (!$user->isEnabled()) {

            $redirectUrl = $this->router->generate('warning');

            $event->setController(function() use ($redirectUrl) {
                return new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:
Ok so turns out checking for each controller manually is really bad, as you will miss Controllers from third party dependencies. I'm going to use the Security annotation and do further custom logic in a custom Exception controller or template etc.

Comment: How about using a role `ROLE_USER_ENABLED`? Then check for this role with your firewall

Comment: Show your listener code.  To get the user you just need to inject security.token_storage and then pull the user from it when you need it.  And be sure to listen to the controller event.  And I just looked at your code again.  Absolutely do not mess with setContainer.  That can cause all sorts of unwanted fun.  And I'm pretty sure it does not even work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html) to listen for any new request.

You'll need to inject the user and then do your verification:

```
    <service id="my_request_listener" class="Namespace\MyListener">
        <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.request" method="onKernelRequest" />
        <argument type="service" id="security.token_storage" />
    </service>
```

Edit: Here is a snippet to give an example

```
class MyRequestListener {
private $tokenStorage;

public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}

public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    if (!$event->getRequest()->isMasterRequest()) {
        // don't do anything if it's not the master request
        return;
    }

    if ($this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        //do your verification here
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider adding some details.  And perhaps show how you can check the controller class from a kernel.request event.  Hint: You can't.

Comment: he doesn't necessarily need to check the controller class, if he needs this to work only on some controllers he can name his routes in a certain way and deduce it from that

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that I can just inject the token storage..that was the part that was missing in my original solution.

Comment: You're welcome, i  suggest PapyDanone's approach i think for simple logic it is easily readable.

Answer (score 4):

In your case I would use the `@Security` annotation, which can be very flexible if you use the expression language.

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

/**
 * @Security("user.isEnabled()")
 */
class EventController extends Controller 
{
    // ...
}
```

In the end it's only 1 line in each of your controller files, and it has the advantage of being very readable (a developer new to the project would know immediately what is going on without having to go and check the contents of a BaseController or any potential before filter...)

More documentation on this [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/security.html#using-expressions-for-complex-security-restrictions).

Comment: Interesting solution, but not quite flexible enough for what I need here. There's a downside too though, when a new developer creates new Controllers, it's easy to forget the Security check.

Comment: On further testing, this could work if I just customize the 403 error page to check in Twig if the user is disabled, or if it's a regular 403 error. I have my answer for now, but i'll add a upvote :)

Answer (score -2):

You can override also `getuser()` function in your `BaseController` also.

```
/**
 * Get a user from the Security Token Storage.
 *
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \LogicException If SecurityBundle is not available
 *
 * @see TokenInterface::getUser()
 */
protected function getUser()
{
    if (!$this->container->has('security.token_storage')) {
        throw new \LogicException('The SecurityBundle is not registered in your application.');
    }
    if (null === $token = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()) {
        return;
    }
    if (!is_object($user = $token->getUser())) {
        // e.g. anonymous authentication
        return;
    }

    // Redirect disabled users to a info page
     if (!$user->isEnabled() && !$this instanceof InfoController) {
         return $this->redirectToRoute('path_to_info');
     }

     return $user;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a very bad idea.  Not only will it not work but returning a response from getUser is a strange interface.  Might want to rethink this one.

Comment: You can find base ```getUser()``` function [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L373). And you can change it as per your need.